# Newly installed apps creates multiple app icons

Tags: google-play-store, screen, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, home-screen-folders

My phone is Panasonic P66 Mega with android lollipop version.
When I install a new app from play store or connect to an app with an email, multiple app icons are being created on the screen, which disappears when the phone is restarted.
Since the phone only consists of a home screen (No app drawer) it's annoying to see many icons.

Please let me know how to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1) Try deleting the cache and rebooting. On my phone, you can do it as follows: Settings > Storage > click on "Cached data" and accept.

2) Maybe it's the play store that creates the problem: Go into the settings of the play store and disable "Add icon to Home screen".

Comment: 1. Cleared cached data, but it didn't work 2. Cannot disable "Add icon to Home screen" because the phone only consists a home screen(No Application drawer)

Comment: Did you search for the option in the Play Store?

Comment: Yes. Did, but yet the problem occurs for some apps.